# Pause and resume gmapping?

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone had success with "pausing" a gmapping session (e.g. to change a battery) and starting it up again? Is there a recommended procedure?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11852/pause-and-resume-gmapping?/) by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3838 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer: This currently is not a supported use case and definitely would require changing core code inside gmapping.

More detailed explanations can be found here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/2133/map_server-getmap

http://answers.ros.org/question/415/loading-a-prior-map-with-gmapping

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1